# How to post a status in a facebook group using c# and facebook API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i can post to facebook wall but how should i post a status in a group?

```
 public void Wall_Post_Publish() 
 { 
 FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(); 
  dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject(); 
    parameters.access_token =     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessToken"]; 
    parameters.message = "This is a test message that has been published by     the Facebook C# SDK on Codeplex. " + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString(); 
    parameters.attribution = "Facebook C# SDK"; 

   dynamic result = app.Post("/me/feed", parameters); 

  Assert.NotEqual(null, result.id); 
 }
```

but how to publish in group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the Group ID instead of "me":

```
dynamic result = app.Post("/group-id/feed", parameters);
```

Be aware that you need `publish_actions` and `user_groups` or `user_managed_groups` to post to a group. `user_groups` will not get approved though, so you are better off with `user_managed_groups`.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed#publish